# What is normal capacity?

Tags: definition, cost

The average variable cost will generally fall as output increases from zero to the **normal capacity** output due to the occurrence of increasing returns. But beyond the **normal capacity** output average variable cost will rise steeply because of the operation of diminishing returns.